# Tabs overlay windows topbar in .NET MAUI Windows App

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I am developing a .NET MAUI Blazor hybrid App. The first page is a loginpage, and when the user is logged in, he/she is redirected to the Mainpage which is a tabbed page with the command below :

```
 Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

When testing the application in Windows Machine simulator, the tabs is overlaying the top windows bar (see image below).

Any idea why this is happening? How can I move the tabs lower?

[image]

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code snippet below to navigate to other pages on Blazor Hybrid project.

```
App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
```